# How to resolve 'undefined Module' error when loading npm package in NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json

I am trying to load a package called ['geojson2h3'](https://github.com/uber/geojson2H3) in my `NodeJS` app. After running `npm install geojson2h3`, I tried following the initial code instructions given in `Github` to test it out:

```
import geojson2h3 from 'geojson2h3';

const polygon = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
     coordinates: [
      [
        [-122.47485823276713, 37.85878356045377],
        [-122.47504834087829, 37.86196795698972],
        [-122.47845104316997, 37.86010614563313],
        [-122.47485823276713, 37.85878356045377]
      ]
    ]
  }
};

const hexagons = geojson2h3.featureToH3Set(polygon, 10);
// -> ['8a2830855047fff', '8a2830855077fff', '8a283085505ffff', '8a283085506ffff']

const feature = geojson2h3.h3SetToFeature(hexagons);
// -> {type: 'Feature', properties: {}, geometry: {type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [...]}}
```

Of course, this throws a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error. I then tried using the `NodeJS require` method as such: `const geojson2h3 = require('geojson2h3');`, replacing the `import` statement. This throws an `Uncaught Error: undefinedModule` error. The package shows in my `package.json` file, but I don't see it in my `node_modules` folder. I am assuming that's related to the issue. What did I do wrong here?

*Note: I know that this is a GIS-related package but the issue is a generic NodeJS package issue, not a GIS-specific one.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to how the project is build, basically it does not export a solid version for nodejs. **[image: strong text]**

So to summarise the problem, the peerdependency of h3-js, does not seem to be es-module friendly as you can se below.
[image]

As far as I can tell, the easiest solution for you is to try too use something else open source, but if there is nothing that meets your expectation, I guess you could try to modify h3-js. from node_modules/h3-js.js and the push for necessary changes on the relevant github pages.
[image]

Comment: This is so weird. Their documentation literally says to bring this module in using npm, but it lacks a coherent explanation other than using the import method for initializing it inside an app. As mentioned below, if I put the sample code in my app.js file (its now showing in my node_modules folder), add something like `console.log(hexagons)`,  and then run `>node app.js`, it runs and prints the correct results, but when I launch the index.html thats linked to my app.js, I still get the `undefinedModule` error.

Comment: @gwydion93 they are probably not referring to a nodejs environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `npm i` to install that package.

Comment: I simply ran > `npm i` from my terminal, but it's still not showing the module `geojson2h3` in my `node_modules` folder and I am getting the same `undefinedModule` error .

Comment: What if you run this: npm install geojson2h3 ?

Comment: OK, that's what I did originally. I just refreshed the app and now I see the package in the `node_modules` folder. Oddly, I added a `console.log(hexagon);` at the bottom of the code and it runs fine if I just run `>node app.js`. It prints the object correctly. However, when I launch the app in a browser, I still see the `undefinedModule` error.

Comment: How are you launching the app in browser? What framework/library are you using? Are you using Dojo toolkit?

Comment: I am simply launching an `index.html` file that brings in the `app.js` file with the above code. I haven't brought in the server side code/Express yet. As mentioned, this is a simple `NodeJS` setup so that I can utilize npm/node to test the h3 stuff out. My goal is to bring in some raw geojson files (points), convert them to h3 and then render the hexagons on a web map in my browser.